# passing a variable instead of input file to sed

Tags: python, sed

I have a python program that calls `sed` as follows.

```
url = os.system("sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/' message")
```

message is a variable containing some data.I think sed expects a file in that place. How is this usually done in python

Comment: are you looking for re.sub() maybe?

Comment: Why aren't you doing this  using the `re` module instead? Calling out to the system for a simple regex substitution seems pretty weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python comes with its own internal regex engine, which would be preferable, *especially* since the return code from `os.system()` is the exit code of the program rather than its standard output.

It also helps with portability since calling an external executable may not work on all systems (Windows has no `sed` by default).

For details, look into `re.sub`:

```
import re
url = 'http://xyzzy.com?paxdiablo=awesome'
url = re.sub(r'^[^?]*\?','',url)
url = re.sub(r'=',' is ',url);
print url
```

Or `re.findall`:

```
import re
url = 'http://xyzzy.com?Python=fantastic&paxdiablo=still%20awesome'
args = re.findall(r'[?&]([^?&]*=[^?&]*)', url)
for arg in args:
    (object,property) = arg.split("=")
    print object, "is", property.replace('%20',' ')
```

Or many of the other methods found in the `re` module for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
message = 'asdf proxy=127.0.0.1 fdsa'
re.sub('.+proxy=([^& ]*).*', r'\1', message)
```

yields

```
127.0.0.1
```

Be aware of greedy vs. non-greedy matching at the beginning of your regex.

Comment: what does ` r'\1' ` the second parameter mean?

Comment: @liv2hak The same as it does in your `sed` code...!?

Comment: @liv2hak the r before the single quotes tells python not to interpret backslashes as initiating an escape sequence but take them literally, i.e. \1 as a back reference to the string matched in the first parentheses.